# Shared Library libpython3.5 not found in Docker Container (but override works fine)

Tags: python, linux, docker, anaconda, cntk

I am trying to deploy a Python Webservice (with flask) that uses CNTK in a Docker Container. I use an Ubuntu-Base-Image from Microsoft that is supposed to contain all the neccessary and correct programs and libraries to run CNTK.

The Script works locally (on Windows) and also when I run the container and start a bash from cmd-line with

```
docker exec -it <container_id> bash
```

and start the script from "within the container".

An important addition is that the python script uses two precompiled modules that are *.pyd files for windows and *.so files for Linux. So for the docker image I replaced the former for the latter for running the script from within the container.

The problems start when I start the script with a CMD in the Dockerfile. The creation of the image shows no problems. But when I start the container with

```
docker run -p 1234:80 app
```

I get the following error:

> ...
>   ImportError: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

It seems like the library is missing. But (I repeat) when I run the script from within a bash running in the container (which should only have the containers libraries as far as I can see), everything works fine. I even can look up the library with

```
ldd $(which python)
```

And the file is definitely in the folder. So the question is why python can't find its dependency when running the docker container.

It even gets weirder when I try to give the path to the library explicitely by writing it in the environment variable:

```
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/root/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.2-0/lib/"
```

Then the library it seems the library is found but it is not accepted as correct:

> ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initcython_bbox)

"cython_bbox" is the name of one of the *.pyd / *.so file/library that is to be imported. This is apparantly a typical error for these kinds of filetypes. But I don't have any experience with them.

I am also not at the point (in my personal development) to be able to compile my own files from foreign source or create the docker image itself on my own. I rely on the parts I got from Microsoft. But I would be open to suggestions.

I also already tried to install the library anew inside my Dockerfile after importing the base image with

```
RUN apt-get install -y libpython3.5
```

But it provoked the same error as when I put the path in the environment variable.

I am really eager to know what goes wrong here. Why does everything run smoothly "inside the container" but not with Autostart at Initialization of a Container with CMD?

For additional info I add the Dockerfile:

> # Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
>   FROM microsoft/cntk:2.5.1-cpu-python3.5
>
> # Set the working
>
> directory to /app 
>   WORKDIR /app
>
> # Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app 
>   ADD . /app
>
> RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-pip RUN pip install
>   --upgrade pip
>
> # Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
>   RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
>
> # Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
>   EXPOSE 80
>
> # Run app.py when the container launches
>   CMD ["python", "test.py"]

The rest of the project is a pretty straightforward flask-webapp that runs without problems when I comment out all import of the actual CNTK-project. It is the [CNTK Object Detection with Faster-RCNN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Object-Detection-using-Faster-R-CNN) by the way, as it can be found in the cntk-git-repository.

EDIT:

I found out what the actual problem is, yet I still have no way to solve it. The thing is that when I start bash with "docker exec" it runs a script at startup that activates an anaconda environment with python3.5 and all the neat libraries. But when CMD just starts python this is done by the standard Bourne shell "sh" which (as I tried out) runs with python2.7.

So I need a way either to start my container with bash (including its autostart scripts) or somehow activate the environment on startup in another way.

I looked up the script and it basically checks if bash is the current shell, sets some environment variables and activates the environment.

```
if [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
  echo Error: only Bash is supported.
elif [ "$(basename "$0" 2> /dev/null)" == "activate-cntk" ]; then
  echo Error: this script is meant to be sourced. Run 'source activate-cntk'
else
  export PATH="/cntk/cntk/bin:$PATH"
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/cntk/cntk/lib:/cntk/cntk/dependencies/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
  source "/root/anaconda3/bin/activate" "/root/anaconda3/envs/cntk-py35"

  cat <<MESSAGE

************************************************************
CNTK is activated.

Please checkout tutorials and examples here:
  /cntk/Tutorials
  /cntk/Examples

To deactivate the environment run

  source /root/anaconda3/bin/deactivate

************************************************************
MESSAGE
fi
```

I tried some dozens of things like linking sh to bash

```
RUN ln -fs /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

or using bash as ENTRYPOINT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also found this [GIT Repository](https://github.com/olgaliak/detection-amlworkbench) doing pretty much the same thing I did. And they also need to start their environment. Realizing that I need to learn how to write better Dockerfiles. I think this is the correct way to do it, i.e. using a shell script as ENTRYPOINT

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/run.sh"]
```

which activates the environment, installs additional python packages (this could be a problem) and starting the actual app.

```
#!/bin/bash
source /root/anaconda3/bin/activate root
pip install easydict
pip install azure-ml-api-sdk==0.1.0a9
pip install sanic
python3 /app/app.py
```

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

Comment: Is this an answer? or additional information to your question?

Comment: This is an actual answer to my question. It shows a way to activate a certain conda environment at the start of the container (which is interesting in itself for a newbie like me, since I thought of doing that, but found it nowhere on the interwebs). And since the missing libraries where installed in that environment, it absolutely solves the problem I've been having. Actually I like this answer even better. It seems to be the **right** way to do it and doesn't rely on manually bending environment variables in the right direction. Sorry for the misunderstandings.

Comment: Also: both posts are distinct, complete answers to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround that works for now.

First I manually link python to python3 in my environment:

```
RUN ln -fs /root/anaconda3/envs/cntk-py35/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python
```

Then I add the environment libraries to the Library-Path:

```
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH "/cntk/cntk/lib:/cntk/cntk/dependencies/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

And to be sure I add all important folders to PATH:

```
ENV PATH "/cntk/cntk/bin:$PATH"
ENV PATH "/root/anaconda3/envs/cntk-py35/bin:$PATH"
```

I then have to install my python packages again:

```
RUN pip install flask
```

And can finally just start my script with:

```
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```